# Integration of legacy mySQL database into a new Django ORM powered data structure

Tags: php, mysql, django, integration, django-south

We have a Django project on which we were working for the several past months, and it is basically the new, improved version of an old system that was powered by PHP and mySQL.

Now I need to convert all of the old data from the mySQL tables, into the new Django - ORM based data structure.

I've already created a new Django project name 'integration', and ran

```
python django-admin.py inspectdb > models.py
```

The result wasn't all that good, because we were using MyISAM DB engine, and there are no clear relations between the models.

Also, the models are much different in their design, although the bottom line is the same(same data represented otherwise).

The questions are:

1. First of all, can this task theoretically be handled this way, purely by south migrations from here onward.
2. How can I lose the nasty id(PK=true) column, and the database_name attribute in the Meta class from the output of inspect db without breaking it all.
3. When preforming major changes to the models(several fields at a time, name, length and type altogether for each one), is there anyway to tell south explicitly which field is which, so the data in the existing columns will be migrated correctly?.

Clearly this is my first integration project of this kind of scale, so sorry for all of the ignorant questions.

What approach will you recommend?, any tools to help me out?.

Is it better to go by Induction(from the bigger, more central object, to the smaller ones) or by deduction(the other way around)?.

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted database introspection only once before and the project was abandoned before I could get anywhere with it, so please consider the following suggestions as theoretical only. Incidentally, the db I introspected was a MySQL with an ISAM engine - at least, I think it was.

What I do remember from my limited experience is that the ForeignKey relations were always detected as IntegerFields. However, changing the IntegerField to ForeignKey fields didn't cause any problems, IIRC. Then again, the project was abandoned before I could get anywhere with it.

Here's the article I used while attempting the process: [Tutorial: Using Django's Multiple Database Support](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1242/django_multiple_database_support)

I also got helpful information from this article: [Administer WordPress using Django's Admin](http://www.ianlewis.org/en/administer-wordpress-django-admin).

And finally, [the official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/legacy-databases/) - they are meager, but hey, they are official! :)

Good luck!